# Change png that is used by sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, how can I change the png that is used by a sprite?

The following works, however it seems a bit longwinded and I was wondering if there is an alternative that prevents me from having to call `new`?

```
// create sprite with original png
m_pSpr = CCSprite::create( "1.png" );
m_pSpr->setPosition( ccp( 100, 100 ) );
this->addChild( m_pSpr );

// now change the png that is used by the sprite

// new image from png file
CCImage* img = new CCImage();
img->initWithImageFile( "2.png", CCImage::kFmtPng );

// new texture from image
CCTexture2D* tex = new CCTexture2D();
tex->initWithImage( img );

// finally change texture of sprite
m_pSpr->setTexture( tex );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pack your sprites into a spritesheet, then use CCSprite's setDisplayFrame().

```
// make sure the spritesheet is cached
auto cacher = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
cacher->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Spritesheet.plist");

// create the sprite
m_pSpr = CCSprite::create( "1.png" );

// set it's display frame to 2.png      
CCSpriteFrame* frame = cacher->spriteFrameByName("2.png");
if( frame)
    m_pSpr->setDisplayFrame(frame);
```

Comment: Does this mean that it loads the actual spritesheet into memory only once, and then if I use 2.png as you demonstrated that it will just go to the texture for the spritesheet that already is in memory and that it hence won't have to read the file from disk again? So if I, say, swap 1 and 2 multiple times, it won't ever need to re-read any of them from disk (if I also changed the call for 1.png to spriteFrameByName?

Comment: yeah, texture will be load into memory only once. all sprites use sprite frames inside and all sprite frames just have pointers to the loaded into memory texture. several sprites will use the same texture.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use setTexture method for a single sprite. If you will pack your sprites to atlases(single texture, for example, 2048x2048 pixels with many different frames inside it, that allows to take less memory), this method will set whole huge texture to your sprite. Use setDisplayFrame instead

Answer (score 1):

you can, but what Morion said is correct, try to avoid using below code because it is expensive. try to use TexturePacker and deal with Sprite frames is a good idea.

```
yourSprite->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("2.png"));
```

Comment: `yourSprite->setTexture(Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(actualCakePopPath));` works fine for cocos2d-x-3.1